# Spring Batch: How to combine multiple task or get 2 task in single

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am bit puzzled here, I need to do a task similar to the following scenario with Spring Batch

1. Read Person from repository ==> I can use RepositoryItemReader
2. (a) Generate CSV file (FlatFileItemWriter) and (b) save CSV file in DB with the generated date (I can use RepositoryItemWriter)

But here I am struggling to understand how I can give generated CSV file output of 2a to save in DB 2b. 
Consider CSV File has approx 1000+ Person Data which are processed for a single day.

is it possible to merge 2a & 2b? I thought about CompositeItemWriter but as here we are combining 1000+ employee in CSV file so it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `CompositeItemWriter` won't work as you will be trying to write an incomplete file to the database for each chunk..

I would not merge 2a and 2b. Make each step do one thing (and do it well):

- Step 1 (chunk-oriented tasklet): read persons and generate the file
- Step 2 (simple tasklet) : save the file in the database

Step 1 can use the job execution context to pass the name of the generated file to step 2. You can find an example in the [Passing Data To Future Steps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps) section. Moreover, with this setup, step 2 will not run if step 1 fails (which makes sense to me).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, let me try, meanwhile one question as it's going to be a large CSV file, is it a good idea to share from one step to another step? I hope it will be cleared once the 2nd step consume the data ( CSV file )

Comment: you don't need to share the whole file in the execution context, only its name and location so that the second step can access it and save it to the db. You can also add a third step to delete the file once it is saved (this 3rd step can also get the file name from the execution context).